# From strings without punctuation search into master string and take from there slices with punctuation without libraries, possible?

Tags: python, string, slice

I have this homework to do (no libraries allowed) and i've underestimated this problem:

let's say we have a list of strings: `str_list = ["my head's", "free", "at last", "into alarm", "in another moment", "neck"]`

What we know for sure about  this is that every single string is contained in the master_string, are in order, and are without punctuation. (all this thanks to previous controls i've made)

Then we have the string: `master_string = "'Come, my head's free at last!' said Alice in a tone of delight, which changed into alarm in another moment, when she found that her shoulders were nowhere to be found: all she could see, when she looked down, was an immense length of neck, which seemed to rise like a stalk out of a sea of green leaves that lay far below her."`

What i must do here is basically check the sequences of string of at least k (in this case `k = 2`) from str_list that are contained in the master_string, however i underestimated the fact that in str_list we have more than 1 word in each string so doing `master_string.split()` won't take me anywhere because would  mean to ask something like `if "my head's" == "my"` and that would be false of course.

I was thinking about doing something like concatenating strings somehow one at time and searching into the `master_string.strip(".,:;!?")` but if i find corresponding sequences i need absolutely to take them directly from the master_string because i need the punctuation in the result variable. This basically means to take directly slices from master_string but how can that be possible? Is even something possible or i got to change approach? This is driving me totally crazy especially because there are no libraries allowed to do this.

In case you're wondering what is the expected result here would be:

`["my head's free at last!", "into alarm in another moment,"]` (because both respect the condition of at least k strings from str_list) and "neck" would be saved in a discard_list since it doesn't respect that condition (it musn't be discarded with .pop() because i need to do other stuff with variables discarded)

Comment: So `neck` is excluded from your expected output because is not preceded by other strings, so `k=1`; is it right?

Comment: Question: strings of `str_list` can be present in the `master_string` only if concatenated with a space?

Comment: Yes exactly, "neck" is only 1 string so doesn't respect the requirement of at least 1 string before or after. Regarding strings of str_list yes they can be presented in master_string with spaces between them but is missing punctuation.

Comment: And what about the apex? In `str_list` we have `my head's`, but it doesn't match with `master_string`'s `my head’s`. Can we replace all the `'` with `’` in `str_list`?

Comment: This is just an example, anyway i didn't understand what you mean, they're the same string no?

Comment: Oh ok I understood now, it was just a copy - paste stuff i did from alice in wonderland to make this example, in the actual code there won't be issues like this

Comment: Ok. Another thing: in you expected output, why do you keep the `!` in `at last!` but you exclude the `,` after `in another moment`?

Comment: Another misstake, should've been included, i have another function to check if last char is not alpha and delete it in case yes  (this task isn't supposed to do this anyway, just my misstake), edited the misstakes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follows my solution:

1. Try to extend all the basing yourself on the `master_string` and a finite set of punctuation characters (e.g. `my head’s` -> `my head’s free at last!`; `free` -> `free at last!`).
2. Keep only the substrings that have been extended at least `k` times.
3. Remove redundant substrings (e.g. `free at last!` is already present with `my head’s free at last!`).

This is the code:

```
str_list = ["my head’s", "free", "at last", "into alarm", "in another moment", "neck"]
master_string = "‘Come, my head’s free at last!’ said Alice in a tone of delight, which changed into alarm in another moment, when she found that her shoulders were nowhere to be found: all she could see, when she looked down, was an immense length of neck, which seemed to rise like a stalk out of a sea of green leaves that lay far below her."
punctuation_characters = ".,:;!?"  # list of punctuation characters
k = 1

def extend_string(current_str, successors_num = 0) :
    # check if the next token is a punctuation mark
    for punctuation_mark in punctuation_characters :
        if current_str + punctuation_mark in master_string :
            return extend_string(current_str + punctuation_mark, successors_num)
    
    # check if the next token is a proper successor
    for successor in str_list :
        if current_str + " " + successor in master_string :
            return extend_string(current_str + " " + successor, successors_num+1)
    
    # cannot extend the string anymore
    return current_str, successors_num

extended_strings = []
for s in str_list :
    extended_string, successors_num = extend_string(s)
    if successors_num >= k : extended_strings.append(extended_string)

extended_strings.sort(key=len)  # sorting by ascending length
result_list = []
for es in extended_strings :
    result_list = list(filter(lambda s2 : s2 not in es, result_list))
    result_list.append(es)
print(result_list)      # result: ['my head’s free at last!', 'into alarm in another moment,']
```

Comment: This could've worked but i can't import libraries to solve this, is against the rules

Comment: @Krist I updated the answer with a better solution

Comment: Thanks! Going to check it now

Comment: I'm tring to understand how it works to integrate it in my code. Since "k" is a value that can change from a run of the code to another, is this gonna work anyway?

Comment: @Krist I generalized the code for any possible `k`. Now you'll obtain `['my head’s free at last!', 'into alarm in another moment,']` with `k=1` and `['my head’s free at last!']` with `k=2`.

Comment: Ok i just changed the successors_num to 1 because otherwise it ignores the strings of length 2 and looks like it's working fine!

Comment: Did it, thanks again now i'm trying to understand how it works to have it in mind for the future

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you again but I'm trying to figure out which could be a way to save the discarded  strings in a list. I tried adding an "else" during successor check to save them in a discard_list (and added that to the return stuff of the function) it gave errors regarding other strings, something regarding "too many unpacks"

Comment: @Krist Sorry but according to SO rules you should open a new question. Feel free to link it here

Comment: i just realized that the test program have prohibited the lambda function, basically i can't use this code...

Comment: @Krist That lambda function just removes the elements of `result_list` that are equal to `es`. You can simply replace it with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Ive got two different versions, number 1 gives you neck :(, but number 2 doesn't give you as much, here's number 1:

```
master_string = "Come, my head’s free at last!’ said Alice in a tone of delight, which changed into alarm in another moment, when she found that her shoulders were nowhere to be found: all she could see, when she looked down, was an immense length of neck, which seemed to rise like a stalk out of a sea of green leaves that lay far below her."

str_list = ["my head's", "free", "at last", "into alarm", "in another moment", "neck"]

new_str = ''

for word in str_list:
    if word in master_string:
       new_str += word + ' '
            

print(new_str)
```

and here's number 2:

```
master_string = "Come, my head’s free at last!’ said Alice in a tone of delight, which changed into alarm in another moment, when she found that her shoulders were nowhere to be found: all she could see, when she looked down, was an immense length of neck, which seemed to rise like a stalk out of a sea of green leaves that lay far below her."

str_list = ["my head's", "free", "at last", "into alarm", "in another moment", "neck"]

new_str = ''

for word in str_list:
    if word in master_string:
        new_word = word.split(' ')
        if len(new_word) == 2:
            new_str += word + ' '
            

print(new_str)
```